# A shared Word document not displaying correctly on different computers

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-teams, flowchart

Me and my classmates are making a flowchart but the full document is not showing up on my screen. Sometimes it would mess it up so the boxes would be all over the place and sometimes it would only show a couple of arrows. How do we fix this? (We are using version 2108 on word)

Pictures:

The classmates screen that has the full document showing

[image: classmates screen]

My screen that is showing an old version of the document

[image: old version on my screen]

The classmates screen that is showing a messed up version of the document

[image: classmate's screen messed up]

Comment: Are you all using the same version of Word?

Comment: Please check the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The third (messed up) screenshot shows [Word Online](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx). This is a different program that works on the same files. It has different (fewer) features and can give results like this. It likely will look like that if you open it in Word Online as well. That classmate should open the document in the full desktop version of Word.

The others likely are explained in Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page: [Why has my document changed when I open it on a different computer?](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TextReflow.htm)

> Because Word is a WYSIWYG application, it will always try to represent
> on screen the result you will get if you print on the printer that is
> currently selected. Unless you have changed the active printer in
> Word, this will be the printer set as the Windows default.
>
> Changing printer drivers will almost always change the layout at least
> slightly and sometimes radically. `***`

> There are a number of ways to minimize the changes that can occur when
> you change printers or drivers:
>
> Don't use hard page breaks! Using hard page breaks `(Ctrl+Enter)` just
> makes matters worse. For example, suppose you have inserted a page
> break at the end of every page. If the copy that fits on one page
> using one printer then runs just one line over using a different one,
> you’ll end up with alternate pages containing only a single line of
> text and a page break, thereby doubling the length of the document.
>
> Instead, use style and paragraph formatting to keep text together.
> Judicious use of “Keep with next,” “Keep lines together,” and “Page
> break before” formatting will keep important sections together. These
> settings are found on the Line and Page Breaks tab of the Paragraph
> dialog, accessed from the Format menu (or shortcut menu) in Word 2003
> and earlier; in Word 2007 and above, use the “dialog launcher” arrow
> in the bottom right corner of the Paragraph group on the Home or Page
> Layout tab of the Ribbon or the Paragraph… entry on the shortcut
> (right-click) menu.
>
> There is also a Compatibility Option, “Use printer metrics to lay out
> document,” that may make a difference. `***`  In Word 2007 and
> 2010, go to Office Button | Word Options | Advanced, scroll to the
> very bottom, and click on the + beside “Layout Options.” This option
> is not available in Word 2013 and 2016.

(nor in Word 2019/365)

> What works best to preserve the look of your document, however, is to
> select the printer on which you will ultimately be printing the
> document (even if it is not connected to the printer where you're
> editing). Then you will know exactly where the page breaks will fall.
> Of course, that won't help if you need to email the document to
> others—but the other suggestions will.
>
> If you are emailing the document to others and preserving the page
> layout is critical, one solution is to email your document in Adobe
> PDF format. `***` Word 2010 and above have PDF authoring built
> in.
>
> [This articl](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TextReflow.htm)e copyright © 2003, 2016 by Suzanne S. Barnhill

Also, be sure that the option to "Automatically update document styles" when opening is **not checked** in the Templates and Add-Ins Dialog. (Developer Tab > Document Template).

[image: screenshot of dialog box]

See: [What happens when I send my document to someone else? Will Word mess up my formatting?](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/sharing/willmyformatchange.html) by Word MVP Shauna Kelly.